# declare global property in QML for other QML files

Tags: qt, variables, scope, qml, global-variables

I want to declare a global property in a config file and use it in other files. for example declare `mainbg` in:

**Style.qml**:

```
property color mainbg: 'red'
```

and use it in other QML files (like `view.qml` and `main.qml`). How can I do this work?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use a QML Singleton.

Please reference "Approach 2" on [this page](https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling)
-- The ugly [QTBUG-34418](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34418) comments are mine.

These are the pieces you need:

**Style.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    property color mainbg: 'red'
}
```

---

**qmldir**

This file must be in the same folder as the singleton .qml file (`Style.qml` in our example) or you must give a relative path to it. `qmldir` may also need to be included by the .qrc resource file. More information about qmldir files can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html).

```
# qmldir
singleton Style Style.qml
```

---

**How to Reference**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import "."  // this is needed when referencing singleton object from same folder
Rectangle {
    color: Style.mainbg  // <- there it is!!!
    width: 240; height 160
}
```

This approach is available since Qt5.0. You need a folder `import` statement even if referencing the QML singleton in the same folder. If is the same folder, use: `import "."` This is the bug that I documented on the qt-project page (see QTBUG-34418, singletons require explicit import to load qmldir file).

Comment: Why not just a simple `.pragma library` javascript file?

Comment: As [tonytony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1096537/tonytony) answered, `.pragma library` does not guarantee a shared instance. A singleton lets you change a global style on-the-fly with all bindings updating to show the same font, color, etc.

Comment: After few years I blindly suggest a Q_PROPERTY in a dedicated style class rather than abusing the QML layer for this kind of needs, it is way more reliable

Answer (score 29):

Basically, if you don't need property binding (if you value is a constant and will not need to be notifiable on change) you can define it in a Javascript shared library, like this :

```
// MyConstants.js
.pragma library
var mainbg = "red";
```

And use it in QML like this :

```
import "MyConstants.js" as Constants

Rectangle {
     color: Constants.mainbg;
}
```

But the bad side of this are : 
- no strong typing (JS doesn't really know about types) so you could put anything even if it is not a color.
- and if you change `mainbg`, the Item using it won't be notified about the change and will keep the old value

So if you need type checking and binding/change notify, simply declare your property as a member of the root object in you main.qml, and it will be accessible from everywhere in the QML application, because the property will in fact be directly registered into the Qml Context object, which is global by definition.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 22):

You can create a js file and import it to all of the files that have to use this property.

js file:

```
//Note: you only need '.pragma library' if you are planning to
//change this variable from multiple qml files
.pragma library
var globalVariable = 20;
```

qml file:

```
import "test.js" as Global

Rectangle {
  id: main
  width: 300; height: 400

  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log( Global.globalVariable)
    //you can also change it
    Global.globalVariable = 5
  }
}
```

Comment: don't forget to put `#pragma library` in there.

Comment: I must notice that `.pragma library` _allowes_ JS file to be used by several QML files, but _does not guarantee_ that there will be only one instance of the library. I've just encountered severe bug in my application that is due to my attempt of using JS library as global state container.

Answer (score 9):

Adding some contribute to @pixelgrease answer, I found another technique that doesn't require the path relative `import "."`, workarounding the bug [QTBUG-34418](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34418). This is useful especially if one has `qmldir` and singleton class in a different place than the qml file where the singleton is used. The technique requires defining a proper module inside the tree structure: the module is then resolved by adding the parent path of the module to the QML engine with `QmlEngine::addImportPath(moduleParentPath)`. For example:

```
qml/
├── <ModuleName>/
│ ├── <ClassName>.qml
│ ├── qmldir
```

In main.cpp you have then:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/qml");    // Can be any directory
engine.load("qrc:/qml/main.qml");
```

If you use resources, qml.qrc:

```
<RCC>
 <qresource prefix="/">
      (...)
 <file>qml/main.qml</file>
 <file>qml/MySingletons/MySingleton.qml</file>
 <file>qml/MySingletons/qmldir</file>
 </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In qmldir:

```
module MySingletons
singleton MySingleton 1.0 MySingleton.qml
```

In main.qml, or any other qml file in a different directory:

```
import MySingletons 1.0
```

Then you use MySingleton class as usual. I attached the example MySingletonWithModule.7z to bug [QTBUG-34418](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34418) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Add this  property in main and you can access it in any qml,this may not be the correct way but this works.

or if you want to group the property add them in a qml
include that qml in main and give an id,now you can access this property using that id

main.qml

```
 Item{
 width:10
 height:10

 Model{
 id:globdldata
 }



 }
```

Model.qml

```
Item {

property color mainbg: 'red'

}
```

you can use globdldata.mainbg anywhere

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Qt 6.2 with CMake, there is property [QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-source-file-property-qt-qml-singleton-type.html), which allows easily use QML singletons without any import and qmldir.

If you have **Style.qml**

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property color mainbg: 'red'
}
```

Set this extra property in **CMakeList.txt**

```
set_source_files_properties(Style.qml PROPERTIES
    QT_QML_SINGLETON_TYPE TRUE
)
```

Use in other files

```
Rectangle {
    color: Style.mainbg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a new QML object file that contains the properties that you want shared across qml files.  Just import it the same way you would any QML object and you have access to properties. Now, if you want to be able to modify these properties and have the changes shared across instances things get a lot trickier and you will most likely want to resort to some sort of solution using the .pragma library js files.  Unless you want to write some sort of C++ alternative.