# Bind to imported Javascript property

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.3

How do I bind to a Javascript resource?

I'm new to QML and are probably thinking about this the wrong way, but in the below example, I'd like the button to say "World" when I press it.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import "model.js" as Model


Button {
    id: button
    text: Model.text

    onClicked: {
        Model.text = "World";
        print("Model.text is:", Model.text)
        print("button.text is:", button.text)
        // Model.text is "World"
        // button.text is "Hello"
        // They should both be "World"
    }
}
```

**model.js**

```
var text = "Hello";
```

I also tried using a `Qt.binding`, but it didn't make a difference.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import "model.js" as Model


Button {    
    onClicked: {
        Model.text = "World";
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        text = Qt.binding(function () { return Model.text })
    }
}
```

The end result I'm looking for is to have properties in a dedicated Javascript resource, such as window height, colors and image paths etc. and have whichever item is using them to stay in sync with any changes made to the resource.

**Edit**

Found a related question: [declare global property in QML for other QML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257946/declare-global-property-in-qml-for-other-qml-files)

Comment: I'd like the button to update its text when the Javascript property is updated. See my updated example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you can't bind QML property to variable from pure JavaScript module. 
My advice is to use lightweight QML alternative - [QtObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html) . You can add custom set of properties and signals to it, for example:

```
QtObject {
    id: mySettings
    property string iconPath: "./icon.png"
}
```

This properties can be binded later exactly as you want.

Comment: I was contemplating this, and it might work well in my case. If I really wanted to keep it within the Javascript realm, perhaps I could even `mySettings = Qt.createQmlObject("import QtQuick 2.0; QtObject {}")` and attach properties from there?

Comment: After some experiments and thought, this one is a winner. Thanks a bunch @QtRoS.