# How to repaint Qt window or tabview in window

Tags: qt, qml

I want to click a button, then popup a dialog box. The Dialog is from Qml, has a label which is made of a variable number from another JavaScript file. When the variable changes, the dialog should repaint, the new number will display on the dialog box.

MyDlg.qml:

```
import "MyJs.js" as MyJs

Window {

    id: myDialog
    width: 300
    height: 300

    TabView {
        id:myTabView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Tab {
            title: "tab 1"
            id: myTab1
            text: MyJs.displayText
            }
     }
}
```

MyJs.js:

```
var displayText = "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

Bindings don't work between QML and separate JavaScript files, only [inline JavaScript expressions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html). I can't find any documentation that explicitly states this, but it has also been mentioned in [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658768/904422).

If you don't want to step into C++, use a QML singleton ([another answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123824/904422)). Here's an example of how you'd use it:

#### MyDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import "."

Window {
    id: myDialog
    width: 300
    height: 300


    TabView {
        id:myTabView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Tab {
            title: MySingleton.displayText
            id: myTab1

            Button {
                text: "Click to change singleton property"
                onClicked: MySingleton.displayText = "Hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### MySingleton.qml

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQml 2.0

QtObject {
    property string displayText: ""
}
```

#### qmldir

```
singleton MySingleton MySingleton.qml
```

More information:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-3
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html#contents-of-a-module-definition-qmldir-file