# Dynamically change QML Theme at runtime on MouseClick

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.5

I have *Theme1.js* which has the property variables related to *Theme 1* styling. I have the same for *Theme 2* with *Theme2.js*.
Now, in **main.qml**, if I click on the `MouseArea`, the theme should toggle between the two. I found that traditional import statements don't exist in QML. Is there another way for this?

**Theme1.js**

```
var color="red";
var textString="This is Theme1"
```

**Theme2.js**

```
var color="green";
var textString="This is Theme2"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "Theme1.js" as Theme //default Theme 

Window {
    visible: true
    color:Theme.color

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            // Toggle between themes.
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: Theme.textString
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it is not advised to use a `js` library to store values that you will bind to later. [Here is some documentation advising not to bind to `var` types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#bindings). You should consider transforming your libraries into `QtObject` singletons.

Use libraries only as libraries for functions.

To change the theme, you might have one Singleton `Style`

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {
    property Theme current: theme1
    property Theme theme1: Theme1 { }
    property Theme theme2: Theme2 { }
}
```

with **Theme.qml** being something like:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
QtObject {
    property color color0
    property color color1
    property color colorX
}
```

and then **Theme1.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Theme {
    color0: 'green'
    color1: 'blue'
    colorX: 'red'
}
```

and **Theme2.qml** being:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Theme {
    color0: 'red'
    color1: 'pruple'
    colorX: 'yellow'
}
```

Then you bind your properties to `color: Style.current.colorX`.

To change the style, just assign another theme to `Style.current`.

---

**EDIT:** *It might be an optimization to use intermediate variables to shorten the paths to the value. It adds the convenience of not needing to use `Style.current.color0` but to use `Style.color0` instead at least.*

You might use this instead for your **Style.qml**:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

Theme { // Use Theme instead of QtObject
    property Theme current: theme1
    property Theme theme1: Theme1 { }
    property Theme theme2: Theme2 { }

    // Bind the `Theme`s properties as intermediate variables to the current Theme.
    color0: (current && current.color0 ? current.color0 : 'defaultColor0')
    color1: (current && current.color1 ? current.color1 : 'defaultColor1')
    colorX: (current && current.colorX ? current.colorX : 'defaultColorX')
}
```

Comment: A useful resource for [Singleton based QML Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257946/declare-global-property-in-qml-for-other-qml-files).

Comment: Could you explain your point a bit more? ofc. you might inline the `Them1/2`-declarations in `Style` or you might use dynamic instantiation to reduce the memory consumption. But to reduce the amount of implicit classes, I think it is beneficial to have one common class `Theme` from which you inherit the concrete `Theme`s. Further having this common base class makes sure, all your styles have the same properties, you are less prone to spelling mistakes, you enable code completion for QtCreator etc...

Comment: The only inconvenience is that your bindings are longer now, i.e. you always have to type `.current.`.

Comment: You are right. I added a suggestion, on how to remove this inconvenience. It might even improve performance [if this counts as intermediate variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#bindings) . I have no data concerning this. At least it allows us to remove any `null`-checks within the application it self. (current might be not initialized at the startup and errors might be thrown)