# Declare specific global objects in QML

Tags: qt, qml, global-variables

I am trying to follow this answer, but for more complicated objects:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25123824/1036082

My files are:

qml.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>Uconsts.qml</file>
        <file>Ucolors.qml</file>
        <file>qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "."

Window
{
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true
    color: Uconsts.colDay.canvas;

}
```

qmldir:

```
# qmldir
singleton Uconsts Uconsts.qml
```

Ucolors.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item
{
    property color canvas: "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Uconsts.qml:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.9

QtObject
{
    property Ucolors colDay:
    {
        canvas: "#eaedf1";
    }
}
```

When running the program, in runtime I get the following errors from the QML side:

```
qrc:/main.qml:10: TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of null
qrc:/Uconsts.qml:6:2: Unable to assign QString to Ucolors_QMLTYPE_0*
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QML does not deduct the type when you use `{}`, you must create the item explicitly

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.9

QtObject
{
    property Ucolors colDay: Ucolors{ canvas: "#eaedf1";}
}
```